# Consume SOAP web service without wsdl using spring framework

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have to call a web service located in http://ip:port/ws which has no `wsdl`.

I can send an `HTTP POST` using Spring framework's `RestTemplate` and get answer as raw input from the service. But this is annoying a bit, that's why I am looking for the correct way to consume this web service without `WSDL`.

Can anybody suggest a 'best practice' way for this task?

Comment: Is this question answered? Is there a way to call to a SOAP web service without using its WSDL?

Comment: @Priyanka I ended up with sending HTTP POST with soap xml body

Comment: Ok. Do you have any references to follow the same approach like you did?

Comment: @Priyanka Hey I added an answer check it

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the best solution, and did some workaround. So as we know the SOAP call in HTTP environment is a standard HTTP POST with the soap envelope in HTTP POST body. So I did the same. I stored the xml soap requests in different place just not mess with the code:

```
public static final String REQ_GET_INFO = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:xyz\">" +
                                                            "   <soapenv:Header/>" +
                                                            "   <soapenv:Body>" +
                                                            "      <urn:export>" +
                                                            "         <cardholderID>%s</cardholderID>" +
                                                            "         <bankId>dummy_bank</bankId>" +
                                                            "      </urn:export>" +
                                                            "   </soapenv:Body>" +
                                                            "</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

And in service layer I used RestTemplate post call with required headers:

```
@Value("${service.url}") // The address of SOAP Endpoint
private String wsUrl;

public OperationResponse getCustomerInfo(Card card) {
    OperationResponse operationResponse = new OperationResponse(ResultCode.ERROR);

    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(String.format(Constants.SoapRequest.REQ_GET_INFO, 
                                                                            card.getCardholderId()), headers);

        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(wsUrl, request, String.class);


        if(!result.contains("<SOAP-ENV:Fault>")) {
            // Do SOAP Envelope body parsing here
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return operationResponse;
}
```

A little bit of dirty job, but it worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks 0bj3ct. I'm not sure what all java packages need to be imported to include Constants and OperationResponse classes. Please include them.

Comment: @Priyanka Constants.SoapRequest.REQ_GET_INFO is the String I already put in the first code block. OperationResponse does not make sense here, it is just specific to my code, your method can return anything, the endpoint will return some data in xml format, you can analyze it and determine the success and error formats, so you can build the right logic for parsing incoming SOAP message.

Comment: @0bj3ct Have you tried the solution shown here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html § 6.2.2. Sending and receiving a WebServiceMessage ? 
It send a String to an URI using the method sendSourceAndReceiveToResult Method of the WebServiceTemplate object ...

Answer (score 1):

There is really no best practice, recreating the WSDL or at least the XML Schema seems like your only option to improve upon your current approach.

Comment: I've read that Spring WebserviceTemplate supports calls to remote web service without WSDL using SAAJ API. But cannot find any tutorial/example about it. PS. I've read springws reference docs

Answer (score 1):

If you're really lucky, it'll return some consistent XML that you might be able to throw an XPath parser at to extract the bits you need.  You might be able to tease out the XML schema either from the data it returns (look for a namespace declaration at the top of the document somewhere, and see if you can follow the URI it references), or drop the data into an on-line schema generator like [this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)